# How to access to control value e.g. textbox.text from a public module?

Tags: vb.net, class, module

I do have the following code and I do want to access inside the `Public Module Test` to the `TextBox1.Text` property.

Why is this not working and how can I achieve to access on a `TextBox1.Text` value inside the `Public Module Test`?

```
Public Class Form1
 ' //some other code...

 'inside this the following line works
 Dim example as String
 example = TextBox1.Text

End Class


Public Module Test
    Dim strTest as String
    'the following line is not working
    strTest = TextBox1.Text
End Module
```

Comment: I would like to see you pass the `String` in `TextBox1.Text` to a method in the Module. Then the Module wouldn't be dependent on the existence of `Form1.TextBox1`

Answer (score 1):

For @BakuBakar...

[image]

The red squiggle means it will not compile. You couldn't put that assignment statement in a Class without a method to contain it. It doesn't work in a Module either.

The following will compile.

```
Module Test
    Dim strString As String = Form1.TextBox1.Text
End Module
```

My idea for the problem... In the module

```
Module Module1
    Private strTest As String
    Public Sub SetStringValue(s As String)
        strTest = s
    End Sub
End Module
```

In the Form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetStringValue(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

This way the module code is not dependent on the existence of Form1 or TextBox1. It could be used in other projects.

Comment: Now I see your point, thats great. Learned something new. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You must use in the beginning of your code the class name. In my case its `Form1`. In additional add inside the module a `Sub`.

```
Public Class Form1
 ' //some other code...
End Class


Public Module Test
    Public Sub main()
        Dim strTest as String
        strTest = Form1.TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You can't put `strTest = Form1.TextBox1.Text` just floating there by itself. You can declare variables at the Module level but an assignment statement needs to be in a method. You can initialize your variable.

Comment: @Mary What do you mean with you cannot? In my case it works. What's the disadvantage? Let me know if there are any. I'm also interested in to know how the code of your suggestion would look like. Simple example would be enough. Thank you.

Comment: It will not compile.

Comment: Can't figure that out. I posted my idea for the problem. Let's agree to disagree. :-)

Comment: You're right, there were the difference between my answer and my real code. In my real code I accessed to the value inside a `Sub`. I have updated my answer for better understanding. This code seems to work too. However the code, described in your answer, is cleaner and more elegant. Thank you again.